# Проблемы с пониманием требований(на английском)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вот оригинал:

`Please write library of classes and test classes for:
 1.1.Initial amount on account is random ( 0 - 15 ) 
 1.2.Person add random (2-5) amount to account 50 times every random (1-3) seconds
 1.3.Person add random (3-6) amount to account 30 times every random (2-4) seconds
 1.4.Person wait when amount on account will be greater than 10 and gets random (8 – 10 ) amount from account.
 1.5.When two first persons complete adding to account following details should be reported:
 Initial amount; each action time - type – amount - account amount; finish amount
 Note: all persons should act in multithread mode.`

А вот на что хватило меня:

`Пожалуйста напишите библиотеку классов и тест-кейсов для:
1.1. Исходная сумма на счету случайная (0-15)
1.2. Человек добавляет случайную (2-5) сумму на счет 50 раз каждые случайные (1-3) секунды
1.3. Человек добавляет случайную (3-6) сумму на счет 30 раз каждые случайные (2-4) секунды
1.4. Человек ждет пока сумма на счету не станет больше чем 10 и снимает случайную (8-10) сумму со счета
1.5. Когда два первых человека завершают добавление сумм на счет - нужно отобразить следующую информацию:
Исходная сумма на счету; для каждого действия время - тип операции - сумма - сумма на счету; итоговая сумма на счету
Замечание: все люди должны действовать параллельно (в мультипоточном режиме)`

Программу необходимо реализовать с применением synhronized/wait/notifyAll
только вот исходя из моего перевода, монитор можно " притянуть за уши" в пункт 1.4. Но мне интуиция подсказывает, что моих знаний языка не хватает на правильное понимание задачи. Помогите разобраться, за ранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Операции добавления и списания средств не являются атомарными. Они состоят из двух шагов: чтение текущего значения и изменение значения. Плюс операция чтения текущего значения сама по себе может возвращать устаревшее значение. Соответственно вам нужно синхронизировать все три операции при работе с аккаунтом.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Реализовал, все три метода synhronized. Все работает, но вопрос в другом. Я не понимаю в каком порядке должна отрабатывать программа, нет, вернее я понимаю алгоритм и шаги, но в чем логика такого задания. Что он может проверять?

Comment: @YuriyK, а что данное задание должно проверять? Умение работать с потоками, уровень понимания многопоточности. Вот какие 3 метода у вас synhronized? Монитор по какому объекту берете? Захватывают ли монитор операции чтения? Много что можно увидеть.

Comment: @Tachkin, в классе Account метод synchronized replenish()/*пополнение счета*/; метод synchronized bonus()/*снятие бонуса*/; поле volatile long count; Соврал, два метода синхронизированы. В методе пополнения счета происходит чтение текущего значения(по скольку оно volotile, мы спокойны что полученное значение актуальное)и запись нового значения. Метод синхронизирован и насколько я могу понимать, работа этого метода будет выглядеть как атомарная операция. С методом снятия бонуса ситуация аналогична. Может я не прав?